# The OP of a question suggested an edit to his own question?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, user-accounts

I am reviewing suggested edits and got this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3337153). It seems to be the OP's own question, yet the edit is a suggested edit. Is this bug or am I missing something?

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100322/152859

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That user has two separate accounts it seems. The account suggesting the edit is not the account that made the original post. So not a bug.

I have [left a comment for the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766914/disabling-certificate-revocation-checking-for-an-application-on-windows#comment29648989_19766914) suggesting that he merges his accounts.